# Javascript Input Checking

Tags: javascript, xhtml, sudoku

I need you help with a piece of javascript that enables input and result checking from:

**Input attributes will be similar to this on the HTML doc.**

```
<div id="game">
<div id="input1"><input name="01_01" onchange="0" type="text"/></div>
```

I need a tough script to checke againts 81 numbers definied on another array and also need an handler to check the users input againts the answers stored on that array from input boxes above.

Any help is always appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: And how does that string of digits relate to the form? I get a distinct whiff of homework about this.

Comment: If you look at his other questions on SO they don't appear to be homework ones.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
var input = '800500614300000002169074050045020000903000040621008900008100000400060000000039800'.split('');
var answer = '872593614354681792169274358745926783983715246621348975238157469497862531516439827'.split('');

var result = (function puzzleStatus(){
    if( input.join() === answer.join() ) return 'Solved!';
    for( var i = 0, j = input.length ; i <= j; i++ ){ 
        if( input[i] !== '0' && input[i] !== answer[i] ){
           return 'There\'s a Mistake';
        } 
    };
    return 'Correct so far';
}()); // Yields "Correct so far" with above inputs
```

**Edit:** Updated the function to report whether the puzzle is solved, unsolved but correct so far, or contains an error.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/skxHm/1/

Comment: +1 All you need in addition is a handler that will retrieve the input and then put the result somewhere visible, and then to bind that handler to an event (onkeyup or onchange) of each input element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to retrieve all the inputs. Then read each one and stuff it in a string. Finally do a string compare against your answer key to determine whether it is correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/RHzKT/

```
var answers  = "";    
$("input:text").each( function() {
    answers += $(this).val();
});
```